# SSRS multiple dataset problems

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have 3 dataset in SSRS. Is it possible to join these 3 dataset using the lookup function? Normally lookup works for two datsets... But I need data from 3 datasets.

Comment: Have you tried nesting the lookups? What data do you need from 3 datasets? It's difficult to advise further without more details on your tables and what exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all three datasets into one stored procedure and use joins to connect all the tables in the stored procedure. In my opinion stored procedures work better with reports becase once you change the stored procedure you dont have to update it in SSRS just refresh it.